# Measurability of a map that takes a functional to its composition with a linear operator

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces, hilbert-spaces, measurable-functions

- Let $(X,\Sigma_X)$ be a measurable space such that $\Sigma_X$ is countably generated.
- Let $B_b(X)$ be the Banach space of all bounded $\Sigma_X$-measurable functions $X\to\mathbb{R}$ equipped with the sup norm.
- Let $ca(X)$ be the Banach space of all countably additive signed measures of bounded variation equipped with the total variation norm.
- For each $\mu\in ca(X)$, let $\Lambda_\mu$ be the linear functional $f\mapsto\int f\;d\mu$.

**July 8th version:** The question has been revised to exclude the case described in Nate's 7/1 comment.

Consider the sequence $(\lambda_n,\lambda'_n) \in ca(X)\times ca(X)$ such that

1. $(\lambda_n,\lambda'_n)\to(\lambda,\lambda')\in ca(X)\times ca(X)$ in total variation
2. $\lambda_n\neq\lambda'_n$ and $\lambda\neq\lambda'$ for all $n$
3. $||\lambda_n||=||\lambda'_n||=||\lambda||=||\lambda'||=1$

Define the mapping $\phi\colon ca(X)\times ca(X)\to ca(X)$ as follows.

$\phi(\mu_1,\mu_2)=\nu$ such that $\Lambda_\nu(f)=\Lambda_{\mu_2}(\pi(f))$, where $$\pi\colon B_b(X) \to L^2(X,|\mu_2|)$$ is the projection onto the closure (in $L^2(X,|\mu_2|)$, not in the sup norm topology) of $\ker \Lambda_{\mu_1}$. To get $\nu$ such that $\Lambda_\nu=\Lambda_{\mu_2}\circ\pi$, I use the $L^2$-space Riesz representation theorem.

**Question**
Is it the case that $||\phi(\lambda_n,\lambda'_n)-\phi(\lambda,\lambda')||\to 0$

Comment: Is it obvious that $\pi$ maps bounded functions to bounded functions?  A priori $\pi(f)$ is only in $L^2(|\mu_1| + |\mu_2|)$ and perhaps could be unbounded.

Comment: I had overlooked that. As you say, it is not obvious. I will modify the original post so that $\pi$ maps $L^2$ objects to $L^2$ objects.

Comment: I meant to say "$B_b(X)$ to $L^2(X)$".

Comment: Well, it's definitely not continuous.  Let $X = [0,1]$ and $m$ Lebesgue measure.  If I've computed correctly, them $\phi(\epsilon m, m) = 0$ for all $\epsilon > 0$ but $\phi(0, m) = m$.  (Actually, the same should hold replacing $X$ by any measurable space and $m$ by any measure.  Even a one-point set would do.)

Comment: Hi Nate. Thanks for the example. I modified the question so that it excludes the case when the arguments of $\phi$ are linear combinations of each other (and also so that neither is the zero measure). I should have been more precise as this is the case that I am really interested in. Does this change the answer?

Comment: So as currently worded, if $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$ are singular, then $\phi(\mu_1, \mu_2) = \mu_2$, is that what you want?

Comment: That is exactly right.